# Moving files to a directory based on bash output with `tag`

Tags: bash, tags

I'm currently using [tag](https://github.com/jdberry/tag) on OS X in order to retrieve the tag value in bash of the files I have saved in a dumping folder.

The purpose of retrieving these tags is the then move the file to a separate folder.

However, I'm unsure how to parse the output of tag in order to then move the file to a different directory.

Here's what I've got so far.

```
#Allow correct parsing of spaces in a file name
SAVEIFS=$IFS;
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b");

dumpFolder="/Users/me/Documents/Dropbox/Dump/";

tag -l ${dumpFolder}*;


##Unset SAVEIFS
IFS=$SAVEIFS;
```

The `tag -l ${dumpFolder}*;` will give me output that looks like this:

```
/Users/me/Documents/Dropbox/Dump/EUROSTAR-1.pdf Personal,Travel
/Users/me/Documents/Dropbox/Dump/EUROSTAR-2.pdf Travel,Work
/Users/me/Documents/Dropbox/Dump/Eurostar Tickets - September 2014.pdf  Personal,Travel
/Users/me/Documents/Dropbox/Dump/Eurostar-2015.01.14.pdf    Travel,Work
```

The tags returned are `Travel`, `Work` and `Personal`. A file will always be tagged with either `Work` or `Personal` but not both. Any file can have `Travel`.

In order to obtain the tags, I've tried using a for loop, however this returns all the files and their tags on a single line when I attempt to print the tags off.

Either way, I don't know how to move by tag.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

The trick was to use xargs. Thanks to [this page](http://munkymorgy.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/using-xargs-on-mac-terminal.html). I should have noted earlier that I'm on OS X.

The `tag -l ${dumpFolder}*;` can be changed to

`tag MyTag ${dumpFolder}* | xargs -I {} mv {} /path/to/dir/;`

Answer (score 0):

You can always also add some delimiter based separation and output redirection.

For example if you just wanted all files that have the word Personal in them, you could simply do the following:

```
tag -l ${dumpFolder}* | grep -i "personal"
```

This will give you a list of results that have the string *personal* somewhere on the line.

If you then wanted to take an action for each of the personal tagged items, you could do the following:

```
tag -l ${dumpFolder}* | grep -i "personal"|while read each_foldername; do path_to_file=$(echo $each_foldername |cut -d ' ' -f 1); mv $path_to_file /path/to/dir; done
```

This would find lines that match the word personal, then for each line create a variable called path_to_file that would then be the path to where it was in drop box (using the space delimiter to isolate the string that matches the path in the output line) and then it would move the dropbox path to your local dir you defined.